# pick multiple password using expect script

Tags: bash, ftp, expect

This is my script:

```
set pwfl [open "/home/arul/Arul/BPGrep/Rest/Test/p1" r]
set pswd [split [read "$pwfl"] "\n"]
foreach pw \$pswd
log_file [exec date]_Int_Push_FTP.log
spawn ftp oc0151528004 21
set timeout 30
expect "Name (*:*):" {send "arul\r\n"}
expect "*assword:" {send "$pw\r\n"}
expect "ftp>" {send "bye\r\n"}
expect "ftp>" {send "exit\r\n"}
```

And getting an error like this:

> wrong # args: should be "foreach varList list ?varList list ...?
>   command"
>       while executing
>
> "foreach pw \$pswd" (file "Int_Push_FTP_11Jul.expect" line 4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your immediate problem:

```
foreach pw $pswd {
    log_file ...
    ...
    expect "ftp>" {send "exit\r"}
    expect eof
}
```

You did not provide the `command` argument to `foreach`

Some other points of code review:

- Don't escape the `$pswd` variable: that results in, not the list contents, but the literal string
  <kbd>$</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>
- You only need to use `\r` to "hit enter" in a send command, not `\r\n`
- This method of reading the lines of a file will result in a list with a trailing empty element.

  - Assuming the last character in the file is a newline (as any well behaved text file should), then
  - when you split the file contents on newlines, the empty string following the trailing newline will become the last list element.
  - so you get one extra iteration of the loop where you attempt to send an empty password.
  - to overcome this, either:

    ```
    set pswd [split [read -nonewline $pwfl] \n]
    ```

    or

    ```
    while {[gets $pwfl pw] != -1} {
        # your foreach loop  body here
    }
    ```
- Don't forget to `close $pwfl`